# Need to erase child's Facebook account without email address

Tags: facebook

My ex-husband created Facebook accounts for our under-age children. I now can't access the account because I don't have the email addresses to log in. How can I erase these profiles for my children?

Comment: Contact Facebook directly, this sounds like something for their legal department rather than a technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your children didn't create it, you can use the Report button, located on every profile.

Submit a Report > Report User's account > This person is impersonating someone

Answer (score 2):

This partly depends on the age of your children. If they're under the age of 13 then that's a [violation of Facebook's terms](https://www.facebook.com/help/157793540954833/). You can use [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/210036389087590) to report the account for deletion.